# [Generic Video Spec]: Is there any video specification which compatbile with all devices?

Tags: video, video-streaming, h.264, video-processing, multimedia

Is there any video specification which compatbile with all (Desktop and Mobile) devices? (Especially in browsers)

The specification include `bit rate`, `resolution`,etc.

Comment: Can you narrow down "all devices" just a little bit?

Comment: Okay, so I guess we've ruled out... mainframe computers? :-) "Desktop and mobile" is still incredibly broad. Your question is tagged with H.264 so I suspect you're already aware of how that is more or less the standard for video. Are you looking for guidance regarding encoding profile?

Comment: Yup, I am looking for encoding profile that comply with various devices vendor, so it doesn't need to change profile when played.

Comment: Most everything will support baseline (the least complicated profile). 320x240 will cover even the smallest devices, but there comes a threshold when you may wish to crank up the resolution for more capable devices. One-size-fits-all is a difficult strategy.

Comment: at least the profile satisfy this device list https://develop.participatoryculture.org/index.php/ConversionMatrix